# pro.InsertAtHead() call create a program crash

Tags: c++

I minimalized my code to this:

Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

class Process{
    public:
        struct task_struct{
            int data;

            struct task_struct* next;
            struct task_struct* prev;
        };

        struct task_struct* head;

        struct task_struct* GetNewTask(int x){
            struct task_struct* newTask = (struct task_struct*)new(struct task_struct);
            newTask->data = x;

            newTask->prev = 0;
            newTask->next = 0;
            return newTask;
        }

        void InsertAtHead(int x){
            struct task_struct* newTask = GetNewTask(x);
            if(head == 0){
                head = newTask;
                return;
            }
            head->prev = newTask;
            newTask->next = head;
            head = newTask;
        }
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    Process pro;
    pro.InsertAtHead(1);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I found out that the pro.InsertAtHead() call create a program crash. But there is no error message. In the Process class I tried to implement a double linked list. I guess there is the problem.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? What is `Process`?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: @Larsus 
What does QTableWidget have to do with your code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a constructor to the Process class to initialise head to null.

Otherwise you’re writing to an undefined location.